# Error code in R while running bulit-in UCBAdmissions data

Tags: r

I am getting an error "Error in UCBAdmissions$Gender : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"  when running the built-in UCBAdmissions data in R

tb2=table(UCBAdmissions$'Gender', UCBAdmissions$'Admit',dnn = c("Admit", "Gender"))
tb2

I did try is.atomic(UCBAdmissions)   is.recursive(UCBAdmissions) and it is true for is.atomic

Answer (score 0):

The `UCBAdmissions` data is a `table` object.

```
> class(UCBAdmissions)
[1] "table"
```

We may need to convert to `data.frame` before using the `$` for extraction

```
table(as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)[c("Admit", "Gender")])
         Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted    6      6
  Rejected    6      6
```